# Calculating error from accuracy score in Sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I have one question thats maybe simple, but my brain overfited :)

I wrote a code for simple linear regression in `Python` and `Scikit-Learn`, and I calculated score of my model.

```
        accuracy_test = model.score(x_test, y_test)
```

I got the score of 0.97. Does that mean that my error is 0.03 (3%)?
For example, Is it correct to say, that If i predict some value with `model.predict` function, and I get result of 100 with that, that I can say that my result will be in range from 97 to 103 because of my 3% error (score of 0.97)?

Can you say this for `accuracy_score` also?

Comment: I guess that is accuracy and 3% error signifies that among all the data in test case only 3% were falsely predicted.  Your second statement : "and I get result of 100 with that, ...  3% error (score of 0.97)? " is wrong. The error has nothing to do with the range. The error simply says how much of the difference was there in true and predicted. If you run the model again you "might" get different accuracy  and error.

Answer (score 2):

From sklearn's documentation for the score function

```
Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.
```

R^2 is a measure of how well the variability of the data is explained by the model. So, at 0.97, the model is able to explain that really well. And yes, it is a measure of accuracy for regression models. However, you cannot construct confidence intervals with that estimate.

`accuracy_score` is a measure of accuracy for classification models. Again, you cannot construct confidence intervals from the accuracy metric.